# C++: What are pointers' hex values relative to?

Tags: c++, pointers

In C ++ (a 32 bit program) you can get the Hex value of a pointer like so:

```
Class myClass;
DWORD hexValue = (DWORD)&myClass;
```

A hex value might look like `0xFF225290`.

What is this value relative to? The start of all of the memory, the start of the process (in the memory), the start of the class, or something else?

EDIT: I don't believe I was clear enough. By "relative" I meant, if I have a pointer to 0x0000, will this be at the beginning of the memory of the process, or the memory of the system?

I understand that the memory itself is scattered all about, my question is simply of pointer number values. When you get a pointer to something, is the number assigned to that pointer within the range of the entire system, or just your local process's local memory heap? As one answer mentioned, in "Modern OS's" every process has its own virtual memory. This would suggest that 0x0000 is at the beginning of the process's virtual heap, and not the beginning of the physical memory. This was my question.

Comment: What's a "hex value"? How is it different from, say, a "decimal value"? Is the number of fingers on your left hand a decimal or a hex value?

Comment: Read up on virtual memory.  And yeah, a "hex value" is just a number.

Comment: It's implementation-defined.

Comment: It is relative to platform-dependent stuff. Most of the memory models out there are linear now, so the value *might* be a direct offset into virtual memory, but some of us still remember "near" and "far" pointers and the segmented memory model, which were a lot of fun to deal with.

Comment: What is the address 1600 Pennsylvania Ave. relative to?

Comment: You guys are getting tied up on the specifics... Of course that's just a number, I know that. I'm seeing if, for example, I pull a pointer's value from ANOTHER process, will that pointer still work within a different process? 

I'm almost afraid to ask anything regarding this here because apparently anything outside the comfort range of typical programming and code style is downvoted a lot..

Comment: It is relative to the lowest address your application can express. Thus **0x01** is exactly 1 address unit higher than the address **0x00**. Other than that, nobody can say. Given virtual memory, segmentation, etc. entire ranges of your address space may represent **completely** different locations. What is more, data and function pointers are not represented the same way either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not relative to anything. It's a value which represents an address in memory.

Most modern computers have a single contiguous address space; in which case you could say it's "relative" to the start of that space. But that's not necessarily the case - there have been (and still are, in embedded systems, and probably will be in the future) platforms with more complicated address spaces.

To answer the question you meant but didn't ask: on most modern computer platforms, each process has its own virtual address space, so pointers from one process will be meaningless in another.

Comment: I understand this, what I mean is, if I have a pointer value from ANOTHER process, will that pointer work the same in my process? Is the pointer pointing to something within MY process or within others/

Comment: @ChristianStewart: On modern computer processors, no. Each process has its own virtual address space, so pointers from one are meaningless in another.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted to know.

Comment: Essentially what I need this for is, I've pulled the value of a pointer from another process, if I do ReadProcessMemory on that process with the address being the value of that pointer, will this work as expected?

Comment: @ChristianStewart: I've no idea; that's a Microsoft thing, and I never program for Windows. If that's your actual question, it's probably best to ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot say a pointer is relative to anything on modern systems: Pointers are nothing more or less than addresses in the virtual memory space of the process. This virtual memory address space is something entirely abstract conjured up by the OS with some help of the hardware.

As it is, ranges of addresses that are contiguous in the virtual memory address space do not even need to be contiguous in physical memory, the pieces of the virtual memory (called pages) may freely be scattered across the physical memory, the OS can distribute them however it pleases. This breaks any notion of a pointer being relative to anything.

Comment: I think I said this wrong. By relative I meant, if I have a pointer to 0x0000, will this be at the beginning of the memory of the process, or the memory of the system?

Comment: The memory of your process is generally scattered in physical memory, and I mean really, practically and physically scattered. Parts belong to libraries which were loaded earlier then your app, other parts belong to libraries that were loaded later, yet other parts are mapped as working memory for the heap/stack. These are all independent memory mapping operations and the OS has no need to keep everything together. So you can't say that there is a beginning of the memory of the process anywhere.

Comment: I meant, if I cast 0x0000 to a pointer, will this be at the BEGINNING of the process's space or the system's space.

Comment: @ChristianStewart It will be as much at the beginning as 0x1000, as 0x2000, and so on. However, from your comments at Mike's answer, I take it that you are using some kind of debugging interface to read the memory of another process. Since the virtual address is the only means to address memory outside of the kernel, you can be certain that any such interface will use the same virtual addresses as the process itself, so you should be able to use a pointer that you read from another process and use it to read what's behind that pointer. However, this is not true if you program hardware!

Comment: Not an external debugging interface but `ReadProcessMemory()` - thanks though!